# wordpress custom post category (taxonomy) next previous link

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I got custom posts with custom categories. Categories are registered as'timeline_category' and custom po sts as timeline. I got a taxonomy page where I list all the post from given taxonomy.

I was wondering if it's possible to create next/previous link on those taxonomy pages which will link to page with next custom taxonomy (something like next_post_link() but for custom categories).

Arek

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I used this on a shopping cart products page, I think it will work for a general situation.

```
global $wp_query;

echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => str_replace(999999999, '%#%', get_pagenum_link(999999999) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
));
```